# official mongodb go-driver heroku connection to mongodb atlas sandbox

Tags: mongodb, go, heroku, mongodb-atlas

**go version:** go1.11.2

**connnection string:** `mongodb+srv://<username>:<pw>@<host>/test?replicaSet=<replicaSetName>&retryWrites=true&w=majority`

**MongoDB Atlas:** Network access is currently set to `0.0.0.0/0`

**MongoDB Atlas:** Sandbox M0 MongoDB version `4.0.10`

**Heroku MongoDB addon:** Sandbox

I am attempting to connect from a heroku app to a MongoDB Atlas cluster with the above connection string. This works fine locally so I know the connection string is valid. 
However, whenever the app (golang app) starts up on heroku side I am getting the following errors.

```
2019/07/27 16:18:49 server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary
Servers:
Addr: rapi0-shard-00-02- 
yqd60.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 
0, Last error: connection() : x509: certificate signed by unknown 
authority
Addr: rapi0-shard-00-00- 
yqd60.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 
0, Last error: connection() : x509: certificate signed by unknown 
authority
Addr: rapi0-shard-00-01- 
yqd60.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 
0, Last error: connection() : x509: certificate signed by unknown 
authority
```

The errors seem to be TLS certificate related. I am using the [Official MongoDB Go Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)

If this is TLS related why am I not getting this error locally?
I found this issue which seems to be the same as mine, but I am not sure what to make of it .... [Related Issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-835)

Has anyone else had similar issues with connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Heroku using Golang?

Please let me know if you need any more info. I am at a loss. I have tried various combinations of connection strings and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you try upgrading to Go 1.12 and see if you still see the problem ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar I will try when i get home from work. Any reason why you think this may work? It works locally for me so I initially ruled out the go version being the culprit. But certainly worth a try

Comment: This is because as of Go 1.12, CA certs in Keychains are supported if correctly installed. Just wanted to rule that out.

Comment: @WanBachtiar You saved me from going nuts. I upgraded to 1.12 and it was able to connect via Heroku!

Comment: Speaking about going nuts,  worth mentioning that there is also Go Nuts mailing list https://golang.org/help/#mailinglist ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to issue [crypto/x509: root_cgo_darwin and root_nocgo_darwin omit some system certs](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24652). The issue where some CA certs in keychains are omitted.

The fix was released in Go v1.12, and also back-ported to Go v1.11.6.